# $.datepicker.parseDate not working

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am having a problem with formating date datepicker. 
here is the code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
         alert("date test");
         var currentDatef = $.datepicker.parseDate('yy-mm-dd', '22-04-2010');
         alert(currentDatef);
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>


    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Please can you help. It was wroking in the past, but i don't know why it is not working

thanks

Comment: So what have you changed? If it used to work before, and not anymore, something must have happened inbetween

Comment: Open developer controls in your browser and check if there are any errors. We can't help if we can't see the error that you are getting

Comment: @Ish Fady check out my answer ?

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
 $.datepicker.parseDate('dd-mm-yy', '22-04-2010');
```

instead of

```
$.datepicker.parseDate('yy-mm-dd', '22-04-2010');
```